# CodenameOne TestRecorder How-To run test

Tags: testing, codenameone

because I think I recommend CodenameOne to be used for development I try to investigate deeper into it. I just tried out the Test Recorder which generated a test class.
Now my question: How-to use this test class? Do I have to call the test method from the existing UI code using e.g. a button to start it?

Generated code:

```
public class RegisterUserATest extends AbstractTest {
public boolean runTest() throws Exception {
    clickButtonByName("Register");
    keyPress(16);
    keyPress(65);
    waitFor(112);
    keyPress(65);
    setText("Name", "A");
    keyPress(16);
    keyPress(65);
    waitFor(113);
    keyPress(16);
    waitFor(1);
    keyPress(97);
    setText("Email", "");
    setText("Password", "A");
    clickButtonByName("Register");
    return true;
}
```

}

I think the solution is very easy but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on NetBeans right click the project and select "Test". On IntelliJ/IDEA it's under Codename One -> Run Tests.

Notice that the latter has a bug in it that will be fixed in the release coming tomorrow (October 7th 2016).